# How do I open a peplink router's diagnostic report?

Tags: networking, router, report

So I got a diagnostic report from the (peplink) router before restarting it, but it's in a format and possibly an encoding (I can't tell) that I don't have support for.
Has any one else had this problem?
Any suggestions?
I would share it, but I don't know what it contains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagnostic report contains the low level information that should be known by Peplink. I suggest to contact their support and send the report to [them](http://www.peplink.com/contact/support/)

Answer (score 2):

It's a .tar.gz with every byte XOR-ed with 50 (0x32). You can do that for example in [Hexplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexplorer/).

Comment: Can you point to some documentation for this? I just tried this with a diagnostic report from a 5.4.9 firmware diagnostic report and it did not appear to be a valid .tar.gz

Comment: 2DB9 before, 1889 after. That's doing it via selecting everything, and XORing with 50 in the Text field. I get different results if I do the same thing with 0x32 in the Hex field for the XOR operation (I end up with 658B), so it's possible I'm not using Hexplorer correctly. Neither way does it give me a usable tar.gz

Comment: Blah. Using a different tool online for just those first two bytes does show me 1F8B, so clearly I'm using Hexplorer wrong. I'd still love to see your source for this info about Peplink diag files!

Comment: HAH! Got it working, in the hexplorer GUI it's just "32" in the hex field. The same process doesn't work for the config file however. Do you know the magic incantation for that one?

Comment: The source is just looking closely... the first 36 bytes are some kind of header (they look different). If you cut them out the file starts with 1F8B, as every good gz file should. Another educated guess is that there's a tar inside and indeed it is.